# I cannot use apache in front of tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk

I'm trying to set an apache2 server in front of a tomcat 10 installation on a ubuntu server in a virtual box environment.
Both apache and tomcat work good by themself.
I want to use apache with mod_jk to redirect some request to tomcat.
Here my steps.
in server.xml of tomcat I've decommeneted the following lines:

```
<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
           address="::1"
           port="8009"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

I've installed mod_jk with apt:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-jk
```

I've edited the workers.properties file in /etc/libapache2-mod-jk:

```
worker.list=worker1
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.port=8009
```

In /etc/apache2/apache.conf:

```
JkWorkersFile /etc/libapache2-mod-jk/workers.properties
JkMount /sample/* worker1
```

On the server address i can see the apache home page, and in serveraddress:8080/sample I can see the tomcat sample page.
I'm now expeting to see the tomcat sample page also in serveraddress/sample.
But i get a 404 error.
Am I missing some steps?

Thank you.

Comment: Since `localhost` resolves to both `::1` and `127.0.0.1` I would use `ip6-localhost`. Also you need either to provide a `secret` to the AJP Connector or set `secretRequired="false"`.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz If we provide secret in AJP connector, then apache give 403 forbidden error. do we need to add this secret in each https request or do we need to also configure secret in worker.properties file in apache mode jk

Answer (score 2):

- Does /var/log/apache2/mod_jk.log tell you anything? (apart from workers jk-manager and jk-status missing as they're set by default mod-jk conf)
- Did you enable mod_jk in Apache (`sudo a2enmod jk`) and restart Apache (`sudo service apache2 restart`)?
- Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Regards the latter, be aware that a regression bug slipped into libapache2-mod-jk for Debian/Ubuntu in renaming jk.conf to httpd.conf which meant using `a2enmod` doesn't work.

Note the issue here:
https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/liba/libapache-mod-jk/libapache-mod-jk_1.2.46-2/changelog

Said bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=928813

This burnt me big time using Unbuntu 20.04 LTS. If this is the case for you, enable mod-jk by adding a symlink to /etc/apache2/mods-available/httpd.conf in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/

The bug didn't reach Unbuntu 18.04 LTS using a vanilla install of `sudo apt install libapache2-mod-jk`. Not sure on when/where/how fixes trickle down from upstream Debian to Ubuntu

HTH